# Автогенерация ID для объекта

Tags: java, sql

На уровне БД задаю IDENTITY(1,1)

```
@Override
public void createTable() throws SQLException {
    super.executeSQL(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pupils(" +
            "id BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY," +
            "name NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL," +
            "surname NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL," +
            "CONSTRAINT uc UNIQUE (id,name,surname))",
            "Создана таблица " + tableName);
}
```

Делаю INSERT в базу

```
    @Override
public Pupil save(Pupil obj) throws SQLException {
    try(PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO pupils VALUES (?,?,?)")) {
        preparedStatement.setLong(1,obj.getId());
        preparedStatement.setString(2,obj.getName());
        preparedStatement.setString(3,obj.getSurname());
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Запись добавлена" + " " + obj.getId() + " " + obj.getName() + " " + obj.getSurname());
    }
    return obj;
}
```

При выводе в консоль он пишет

```
Запись добавлена 0 Oleg Davidow
```

При добавлении следующей записи выкидиывает ошибку SQL, подразумеваю, что пытается добавить запись с таким же id.
В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public void createTable() throws SQLException {
    super.executeSQL(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pupils(" +
            "id BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY," +
            "name NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL," +
            "surname NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL," +
            "CONSTRAINT uc UNIQUE (id,name,surname))",
            "Создана таблица " + tableName);
}
```

вы не должны сами задавать значения id для таблиц, соответственно - preparedStatement.setLong(1,obj.getId()); - надо удалить.

Comment: Получилось, спасибо, а я могу как то увидеть с каким id оно добавляется
вывод получил такой:
Запись добавлена 0 Oleg Dawvidow
Запись добавлена 0 Olesia Kisel
1 Oleg Dawvidow 
2 Olesia Kisel

Comment: @Saintka - обратится или подключиться к базе данных и посмотреть или вывести в лог то что вы добавили. Это будет уже отдельный запрос select

Comment: а если например приходит объект с id, я использую два конструктора, один принимает на вход id, другой нет, получается мне нужно два запроса INSERT и UPDATE внутри моего метода save?

Comment: @Saintka INSERT - вставка новой строки таблицы, UPDATE  - обновление старой записи, соответственно нужен метод, который будет делать что то вроде этого - UPDATE pupils
SET name  = 'newName' 
WHERE id = 3;

Answer (score 1):

Так попробуйте

```
public Pupil save(Pupil obj) throws SQLException {
    try(PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO  pupils (name, surname) VALUES (?,?)")) {
        preparedStatement.setString(1,obj.getName());
        preparedStatement.setString(2,obj.getSurname());
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        try (ResultSet generatedKeys = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys()) {
          if (generatedKeys.next()) {
              obj.setId(generatedKeys.getLong(1));
          }
          else {
              throw new SQLException("Creating user failed.");
          }
        }

        System.out.println("Запись добавлена" + " " + obj.getId() + " " + obj.getName() + " " + obj.getSurname());
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: К сожалению не срабатывает, ниодну запись не добавляет